# Windows phone 8.1 RT Modify control in another thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous

I have a Async Function. In this function I modify control in the page. Detail like this

```
`async public void methodname(){
await ... dosomething;
control.visibility = visibity.visible;}`
```

And I use

```
 Task.Run(delegate()
 {
     GetDATA();
 });
```

to Run this function in another thread (I want this function run with implicit).
But I have a exception like this. control can't modify in another thread. Anyone know what should I do ?

Answer (score 2):

To update any UI components from a separate thread, use something like so:

```
await Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
{
    //update any UI here
});
```

An example can be found [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/blob/master/Samples/Accelerometer/cs/Scenario1_DataEvents.xaml.cs) around line 113. The code there is called from an event of accelerometer, and thus is a separate thread. Therefore any code to update text boxes in this event is wrapped in the lines I posted above.
I hope this will solve your problem :)

Comment: Yeah Thanks a lot! You know how to sort listitem in listview by some attribute ?